# Prestashop HelperTreeCategories Javascript Error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, prestashop

I generate a Category Tree with the helper class in the following simple way:

```
$helper = new HelperTreeCategories('categories-treeview');
$helper->setUseCheckBox(1);
$helper->setRootCategory(Category::getRootCategory()->id);
$helper->setSelectedCategories($this->getSelectedCategories());

$category_tree = $helper->render();
return $category_tree;
```

On the frontend I recieve a Javascript error saying:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tree is not a function  at
>   HTMLDocument.
>   (index.php?controller=AdminLindCategories&token=25f1a4c…&token=25f1a4c33d9a1…:1046)
>       at j (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
>       at Function.ready (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
>       at HTMLDocument.K (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
>       (anonymous) @ index.php?controller=AdminLindCategories&token=25f1a4c…&token=25f1a4c33d9a1…:1046
>       j @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
>       fireWith @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
>       ready @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
>       K @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2

It seems like the `HelperTreeCategories` automatically writes out some Javascript to the DOM that tries to Check selected checkboxes. It tries to use the following code which cause the error:

```
$("#categories-treeview").tree("collapseAll");
```

I suspect that there is some .js file that I have to include in my controller. Anyone know anything about this? Which .js file is required for `HelperTreeCategories`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `tree.js` file located in the default admin theme in Prestashop that is required to set when you want to use the `HelperTreeCategories`.

So to use it do the following in your controller:

```
public function setMedia()
{
    $this->addJS(_PS_BO_ALL_THEMES_DIR_.'default/js/tree.js');
    parent::setMedia();
}
```

Notice that there might be some differences in the location based on your Prestashop version.